# Lost sender's name in my received emails.

Tags: ios

I recently uploaded IOS7 onto my iPhone 4S and now I can't see the name of the sender of any newly received emails in my inbox. Can anyone help?  Nothing too techy please - plain English needed. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you see for a mail?

Comment: A picture would be appreciated so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: To Focus group.         Then 2 lines of message content preview. ie straight to subject with no sender name above it. Some emails do have the sender name there but some don't. These seem to be from the people who email me most frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Settings" -> "Mail, Contacts, Calendars" 
scroll down to "CONTACTS" go to entry "Short Name" at the bottom of this page uncheck "Prefer Nicknames"